# How to display an image and 2 buttons under it in windows 8 html5 metro app?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In my metro app i am trying to create the home page with an image(first row) and 2 buttons under the image (means next row ).first button "More" should be on the left side of the screen and "Play" should be right side of the screen in second row.

I want top 90%(height) of the screen should be covered with image(width should be the whole screen from left to right) and the rest 10%(which comes in the bottom of the screen) should only have those two buttons.

Can anybody help me with HTML code for this ?

I was trying to use two divisions one for displaying the image and another one for buttons. but currently it displays whole page with the image only and that too only half of the image was displayed.

```
<div style="height:60%;" >
    <img src="images/games.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
</div> 

<div style="vertical-align:bottom;background-color:orange;grid-cell-stacking:columns;margin:4px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-top:40%;padding-left:60%">
    <input type="button" id="btnMore" name="Mute" value="More"  />
    <input type="button" id="btnPlay" name="Play" value="Play" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/nT3eB/

I can imagine you'd want to stretch the picture, or so.

HTML:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="imageSection"></div>
        <div id="buttonSection">
            <input type="button" id="btnMore" name="Mute" value="More" />
            <input type="button" id="btnPlay" name="Play" value="Play" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

And CSS:

```
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#imageSection {
    height: 90%;
    background-image: url(../images/games.jpg);
}

#buttonSection {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:orange;
}

#btnMore,
#btnPlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
​
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't load the .jpg file i gave .when i added the logo.png it loaded it multiple times(almost 45).

Comment: You'll probably have to use '../images/games.jpg' if your images folder is in the root of the site (in stead of in the css folder) :-)

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.its working fine now. I had to add the below code:#homepageimage { 
    width: 100%;   
    background-image: url(../images/animal.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:100%
}

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the new -ms-grid layout type is what you need.

```
<div class="mainGrid">
  <img class="mainimage" src="yourImage.jpg"/>
  <div class="button1">Your Button 1</div>
  <div class="button2">Your button 2</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.mainGrid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 90fr 10fr;
 }
 .mainImage {
   -ms-grid-row: 1;
   -ms-grid-column: 1;
   -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .button1 {
     -ms-grid-row: 2;
     -ms-grid-column: 1;
     -ms-grid-column-align: start;
 }
 .button2 {
     -ms-grid-row: 2;
     -ms-grid-column: 1;
     -ms-grid-column-align: end;
 }
```

For full details of the CSS grid support: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673533(v=vs.85).aspx

This is in-progress standard (I believe webkit is currently implementing it)

Comment: Thanks.Can you also share the link to understand the -ms-grid layout